# Parse.js Binding error

Tags: parsing, backbone.js, typeerror

I'm new to Backbone.js and Parse so apologies if I'm not specific enough.

I've got a view that throws a TypeError upon initialisation that even if I fix by deleting the line in question, just throws up another error in code that is otherwise perfectly acceptable.

Here is the error I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'bind' of undefined views.js:59
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'bind' of undefined views.js:59
```

Here is the view's init function, lines 59 and 60:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.model.bind("reset", this.render, this);
    this.model.bind("add", this.appendNewJob, this);
}
```

Please let me know in the comments if you need more code to go on.
UPDATE: as requested, my render and appendNewJob functions:

```
render: function(eventName) {
    _.each(this.model.models, function(job){
        this.appendNewJob(job);
    }, this);
    this.delegateEvents();
    return this.el;
},
appendNewJob: function(job){
    this.$el.append(new JobListItemView({
        model: job
    }).render());
}
```

My router:

```
var AppRouter = Parse.Router.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        $('#header').html(new HeaderView().render());
    },
    routes: {
        "": "list",
        "jobs": "list",
        "settings": "viewSettings"
    },
    list: function() {
        var self = this;
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
            if(response.status === 'connected') {
                // logged in.
                self.before(function() {
                    self.showView('#content', new JobListView());
                });
            } else if(response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                // not authorized.
            } else {
                // not connected.
                $('#app').hide();
                self.before(function() {
                    self.showView('#login', new StartView());
                });
            }
        });
    },
    viewSettings: function() {
        var self = this;
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
            if(response.status === 'connected') {
                // logged in.
                self.before(function() {
                    self.showView('#content', new SettingsView());
                });
            } else if(response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                // not authorized.
            } else {
                // not connected.
                $('#app').hide();
                self.before(function() {
                    self.showView('#login', new StartView());
                });
            }
        });
        $('#filterBar').hide();
    },
    showView: function(selector, view) {
        if(this.currentView) this.currentView.close();
        $(selector).html(view.render());
        this.currentView = view;
        return view;
    },
    before: function(callback) {
        if(this.jobList) {
            if(callback) callback.call(this);
        } else {
            this.jobList = new JobCollection();
            var self= this;
            this.jobList.fetch({
                success: function() {
                    var joblist = new JobListView({
                        model: self.jobList
                    }).render();
                    $('#content').html(joblist);
                    if(callback) callback.call(self);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

UPDATE: I am also using the parse js library in place of backbone.

Comment: you definitely need to paste more code.

Comment: Can you paste the code where you initialize the view.. probably your `router`

Comment: I've just modified the question as I forgot to add that I am using the Parse library rather than backbone.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing your view without passing in the `model` option. The error is a standard javascript error, which tells you that on line 59 `this.model` is undefined:

```
this.model.bind("reset", this.render, this);
```

The view cannot have a `this.model` property, unless you give the model to the view!

So instead of:

```
new JobListView();
```

You need to initialize it with

```
new JobListView({model: <insert your model here>});
```